# WSO2 EMM 2.0.0 Android Client application connection failed

Tags: android, wso2, wso2-iot

I have configured WSO2 EMM 2.0.0 on Windows 8 machine with JDK 7.0 and on android device I installed client application from [WSO2 EMM Android Client](https://github.com/wso2/product-mdm/tree/master/modules/mobile-agents/android/client)

then I started the WSO2 EMM server using wso2server.bat file on windows 8 machine. Server started successfully and its address is 192.168.1.11:9443.
When I enter this address on android client application with administrator credentials for BYOD then on android application shows connection failed message "Server is unavailable. Please contact administrator".
But when I enter https://192.168.1.11:9443/emm on android device browser the
EMM console get opened on android device browser.

I set up the JAVA_HOME and PATH environment variable with their respective path value suggested on WSO2 EMM documentation. And I entered server address "192.168.1.11:9443" on android client application with username "admin" password "admin".

Please help me whats issue is causing on android client application to connect with WSO2 EMM server?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

Are you using this with https? First try to enter the URL as http://{ip address}:9763 in Android agent and see whether it works. If not you have missed some configuration [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM200/General+Server+Configurations). Upon properly configuring SSL you should be able to invoke it with https://{ip address}:9443 url.